# webview error page could not be load

Tags: android, webview

I did this code to load error page when connection is down. I am trying to load a file from assets folder but unable to load. Please, somebody to help me.
I have shown progress bar as well before the loading page.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());
  /*  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String faillingUrl ){
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Splash-LS.png");
        }
    });*/
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        setTitle("Chargement ...");
             if (progress == 100){
                 frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 setTitle(view.getTitle());
             }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);


    }
       /* public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String faillingUrl ){
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Splash-LS.png");
        }*/
 });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl(webAddress);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String faillingUrl ){
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/erreur.html");
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: "unable to load" is not enough - please give the exact details. What do you see? Do you get an error in the log? Also, What is the format of "webAddress"?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english to explain what I need. I just want to show an Image or webpage when internet is not avaible. I don't want to show the default error message when the website site is not available. Hope this could help you to help me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several reasons for that, but most probably - your are using `android_assets` instead of `android_asset`.

This should be the correct line for loading the html file from assets

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erreur.html");
```